# В строке где нет ":" найти шаблон

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть список путей:

```
\test\{list}\tasks
\test\{list}\{task}
\task\{id:[0-9]{6}}
\file\{task:[0-9]{6}}*name
\file\{test}*name
```

Как найти все блоки {} в путях где нет :?
В идеале не привязываться к разделителям(\).

Ожидаемый результат:

```
\test\{list}\tasks  -  {list}
\test\{list}\{task}  -  {list},{task}(2 блока)
\task\{id:[0-9]{6}}  -  (не найдено)
\file\{task:[0-9]{6}}*name  -  (не найдено)
\file\{test}*name  -  {test}
```

Comment: `(?<![\]\.]){[^:{}]*}`  https://regex101.com/r/OXUKSm/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения. Они предназначены для того, чтобы находить в строке нужные вам подстроки, соответствующие определённому шаблону. Вот ваше [регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/FmlF1y/1):

```
{[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^:][a-zA-Z0-9]*[^{}]}
```

Что в нём происходит:

1. Нужная нам подстрока начинается с фигурной скобки `{`
2. Потом идёт некоторое количество латинских букв или цифр *(ноль или более)*: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`
3. Потом мы проверяем убеждаемся в том, что в нашей подстроке отсутствует двоеточие: `[^:]`
4. А после опять идёт ноль или более латинских букв или цифр.
5. В конце проверяем, чтобы не было скобок *(это специально на случай `\task\{id:[0-9]{6}}`)*

Конкретно приведённые вами строки отлично фильтруются, как вы и хотели. К сожалению, я не знаю все возможные строки, которые будут фильтроваться. Возможно, вам придётся самостоятельно дополнить это регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из того, что под словом "блок" подразумевается подстрока, начинающаяся с `{` и буквы, после которых может быть ноль и более символов, отличных от двоеточия и фигурных скобок, за которыми следует символ `}`, я считаю, что вам подойдёт

```py
re.findall(r'{[a-zA-Z][^{}:]*}', text)
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/DnRRsr/1/).

*Подробности*

- `{` - символ `{`
- `[a-zA-Z]` - одна буква из набора ASCII
- `[^{}:]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от `{`, `}` и `:`
- `}` - символ `}`.

[Пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/2zbwty):

```py
import re
text = r"\test\{list}\tasks, \test\{list}\{task}, \task\{id:[0-9]{6}}, \file\{task:[0-9]{6}}*name, \file\{test}*name"
print( re.findall(r'{[a-zA-Z][^{}:]*}', text) )
# => ['{list}', '{list}', '{task}', '{test}']
```